# Is field strength a scalar or a vector?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, field-theory

I'd imagine strength to be a scalar quantity. My intuition says that how strongly a force is experienced, ie its magnitude, has nothing to do with the direction it is experienced in. From what I understand, field strength is a measure of the strength of the force due to a field at a point in space. But many sources argue that since force is a vector quantity, it follows that field strength is also a vector quantity.

So, is field strength a vector or a scalar?

**Sources:**
Scalar:
[www.its.bldrdoc.gov](https://www.its.bldrdoc.gov/fs-1037/dir-015/_2219.htm#:%7E:text=The%20magnitude%20of%20an%20electric%2C%20magnetic%2C%20or%20electromagnetic%20field%20at%20a%20given%20point.)
[vedantu.com](https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/the-strength-of-the-force-is-expressed-by-a-class-11-physics-cbse-5f503aed4ec624396d23e679#:%7E:text=But%20the%20strength%20of%20the%20force%20is%20scalar)
[quora.com](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-reasons-why-an-electric-field-strength-is-considered-a-vector-quantity#:%7E:text=the%20electric%20field%20strength%20somewhere%20is%20a%20scalar%20quantity)
[math.answers.com](https://math.answers.com/Q/Is_magnetic_field_strength_a_vector_quantity)
[math.answers.com](https://math.answers.com/Q/Is_magnetic_field_strength_scalar_or_vector_quantity)

Vector:
[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/field-strength)
[physicsclassroom.com](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-4/Electric-Field-Intensity#:%7E:text=per%20Charge%20Ratio-,Electric%20field%20strength%20is%20a%20vector%20quantity,-%3B%20it%20has%20both)
[math.answers.com](https://math.answers.com/Q/Why_is_an_electric_field_strength_a_vector_quantity)
[topperlearning.com](https://www.topperlearning.com/answer/is-electric-field-intensity-a-scalar-or-a-vector-quantity/uy3bet544)
[flashcardmachine.com](https://www.flashcardmachine.com/gravitational-fields.html#:%7E:text=Field%20strength%20is%20a%20vector)

Answer (score 1):

It will depend, i don't know from before this kind of field, but as you say, "Field strength is a measure of the strength of the force due to a field at a point in space", if what you are measuring is the net force or the module of it, it will be a scalar field, but if the direction have something to do, if for example you have a scalar product that depend on the angle, it will be a vector field. But it will depend on the definition.

It depend on what you are calling "strength"

Comment: What make most sense to me is that this strength is related with the net force, but maybe for problems of traduction we are not interpretating the same the concept of strength